# iOS Mirroring MPMoviePlayerController to TV with TV screen playback in fullscreen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, airplay

I have an App with video (locally stored) playback using MPMoviePlayerController

```
    NSString *deviceDir = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:WZLDEVICEPATH];
NSString *videopath = [deviceDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:video]
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videopath];
player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
CGRect viewInsetRect = CGRectInset (playerframe,
                                            0.0,
                                            0.0 );
        /* Inset the movie frame in the parent view frame. */
[[player view] setFrame:viewInsetRect];
[player view].backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[player view].tag = TAG_VIDEO_PLAYER;
player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
[player prepareToPlay];
[self.view addSubview: [player view]];
```

Now I need to mirror the App to an external device, the mirroring just works fine to the second screen (TV), but the TV playback is in the same resolution(width x height) as it is in the iPad, I have to make the TV playback in fullscreen. Is there any way to make sync playback in two devices at different resolution.

I have tried for the multiple window with different instance of MPMoviePlayerController but there the sync playback is getting affected. Is there some work around to overcome these issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[secondScreen  setOverscanCompensation: UIScreenOverscanCompensationInsetApplicationFrame];
```

With the above settings videos in 16:9 resolution starts playing by filling the whole screen & 4:3 videos with black bars on top & bottom which is ok, as we know to keep the aspect ratio it need to be there.

Note I have also noticed when we use iPad Mini the older behaviour still keep on coming.